# vba loop through string to find date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through filenames to find a date. I do not have a specific date I'm looking for, just trying to pull a date if one exists in the filename . Problem is that the users don't use the same format everytime so I have everything from 1-1-14 to 01-01-2014 to consider. I wrote a function for this but when the date in the file name is 06-23-2014 I get a return of 6/23/201. Example file names are "F2 A-Shift 06-23-2014 Daily Sustaining Report.xls" and "F1C-Shift 6-25-14 Daily Sustaining Report.xls". Any help on a viable solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
Function GetDate(strName As String) As Date

    Dim intLen As Integer, i As Integer

    intLen = Len(strName)

    If intLen <= 10 Then Exit Function

    For i = 1 To intLen - 10
        If IsDate(Mid(strName, i, 10)) = True Then
           GetDate = (Mid(strName, i, 10))
           Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    GetDate = "1/1/2001"
End Function
```

Comment: are the dates always going to have spaces before and after>

Comment: Do you really need to return the date in the same format as it exists in the file name?

Comment: Do you need to use this as a worksheet formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is you are assuming that a date is always 10 characters and 2nd is you are checking for a valid date and as soon as you get a valid date you are existing your loop.

The code you are using will never recognize 6-1-14 as a valid date because even with a trailing and leading space, it will never be a valid date when you are looking at blocks of 10 characters.

The issue with your 2nd problem lies with `If IsDate(Mid(strName, i, 10)) = True Then`

There are a number of things Excel does too well and one of which is guess what you are trying to do.  You are assuming that a leading space on a date such as " 06-23-201" would not be considered a valid date, but you are incorrect.  The `IsDate` function sees this as a valid date so your loop exits before you even get to the "4".  This is why you are only getting `6/23/201`.

So to solve both of your problems, you need to modify your logic.  Instead of focusing on checking 10 characters at a time, you should use the fact that your dates will always seem to have a leading or trailing space.

```
Function GetDate(strName As String) As Date

    Dim FileNameParts as Variant
    Dim part as Variant

    FileNameParts  = Split(strName," ")

    For Each part in FileNameParts  
        If IsDate(part ) = True Then
           GetDate = part
           Exit Function
        End If
    Next    

    GetDate = "1/1/2001"
End Function
```

Comment: Probably the best answer, so long as the date is space delimited (or, at least, delimited with a known delimiter).

Comment: I looked through 2 years worth of filenames and found the date to always be space delimited, making this a good option. Testing revealed no issues. Thanks for the tutelage.

Comment: @HansRFranz if you find other possible delimiters (like a dash or other such character), there are worksarounds to deal with multiple delimiters, such as [how to split a string with multiple delimeters in vba excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680490/how-to-split-a-string-with-multiple-delimeters-in-vba-excel), but the presence of the dash in the dates could make this more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get the result you see in your function is because the IsDate function ignores leading spaces.  So "  1/1/01" will be seen as a date.  In order to make your function work, you would probably need to check that; perhaps by ensuring the the first and last characters are digits; determining the length; and ensuring that there are spaces around the date.

Another method would be to use a regular expression to parse all that out.  Without checking for invalid dates (e.g. feb 31), the following is one way to do that:

```
Option Explicit
Function GetDate(S As String) As Date
  Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "\b(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2}\b"
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        GetDate = MC(0)
    Else
        GetDate = "1/1/2001"
    End If
End With
End Function
```

With a little effort, I have modified your original approach slightly which I believe should also work:

```
Function GetDate(strName As String) As Date
  Dim intLen As Integer, i As Integer
  Dim S As String

    intLen = Len(strName)
    If intLen <= 10 Then Exit Function
    For i = 1 To intLen - 10
        If Mid(strName, i, 1) Like "#" Then
            S = Mid(strName, i, InStr(i, strName, " ") - 1)
            If IsDate(S) Then
                GetDate = S
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    GetDate = "1/1/2001"
End Function
```

Comment: beautiful solution. :) one can then use a date-parser in my answer below to verify validity of the datestring

Answer (score 0):

Useful input thanks !

I have tweaked it to accomodate my needs and the result reads as follows:

Sub DateGet()

```
Dim datDate                         As Date
Dim intDay                          As Integer
Dim intMth                          As Integer
Dim intYr                           As Integer
Dim i                               As Integer
Dim strSeparator                    As String

datDate = DateStrip(Selection.Value)

For i = 1 To Len(datDate)
    If Not IsNumeric(Mid(datDate, i, 1)) Then
        strSeparator = Mid(datDate, i, 1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
intDay = Mid(datDate, 1, i - 1)
intMth = Mid(datDate, i + 1, InStr(i + 1, datDate, strSeparator) - i - 1)
intYr = Mid(datDate, InStr(i + 1, datDate, strSeparator) + 1, 4)
'Debug.Print intDay & strSeparator & intMth & strSeparator & intYr
```

End Sub

Function DateStrip(strName As String) As Date
    Dim intLen                          As Integer
    Dim i                               As Integer
    Dim S                               As String

```
intLen = Len(strName)
If intLen <= 10 Then Exit Function
For i = 1 To intLen
    If Mid(strName, i, 1) Like "#" Then
        S = Mid(strName, i, InStr(i + 1, strName, " ") - i)
        If IsDate(S) Then
            DateStrip = S
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own RegEx function to simplify:

```
Function RegEx(Target As String, RegExpression As String, _
               Optional ReplaceString As String, Optional xIgnoreCase As Boolean, _
               Optional xGlobal As Boolean, Optional xMultiLine As Boolean)

    Dim regexOne As Object
            
    Set regexOne = New RegExp
    regexOne.Pattern = RegExpression
    If xIgnoreCase Then regexOne.IgnoreCase = xIgnoreCase
    If xGlobal Then regexOne.Global = xGlobal
    If xMultiLine Then regexOne.MultiLine = xMultiLine
    
    If regexOne.Test(Target) Then
        If IsMissing(ReplaceString) Then
            RegEx = regexOne.Execute(Target)
        Else
            RegEx = regexOne.Replace(Target, ReplaceString)
        End If
    End If
        
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
Function DateValueFn(Str as String) as Date
    On Error Goto ERRORHANDLER
    DateValueFn = DateValue(Str)
    Exit Function
ERRORHANDLER:
    DateValueFn = 0
End Function
```

Now if the user gives an invalid output, this function returns 0, else the date. You may do a check wherever it gets called and use it.

Now since the filenames are stored as `SomestringDateString` where both substrings are of variable length, the user will need to run a loop to check all substrings such that (following code exists in a for loop)

```
SubStr = Right(FileName, i)    'i loops from 6 to 16 or till length of FileName
DtVal = DateValueFn(SubStr)
If DtVal !=0
    ' Date Found, do something, raise a flag perhaps and inspect DtVal
    Exit For
Else
    ' Date Not Found, continue looking, maybe raise a flag if no date found for all i
End if
```

---

And Finally if filenames are in a format `Somestring1DateStringSomestring2` the above loop needs to become a double-doop with `Right` replaced by a `Mid` function so all possible subsets of the string, from characters 1:6 to characters N-5:N and then 1:7 to N-6:N, etc. need to be checked.

Comment: Um.... this is only going to work for the OP's situation when the entire file name is a date, otherwise you are only ever going to get a 0.

Comment: I'd assume that the OP should be capable of using this to parse subsets of the string as date, e.g. pluck out subsections of the string from sizes 6 (1/2/03) to 16 (December 8, 1994) depending on the business logic of the dates being used in naming. The heuristic would depend on how the dates are customarily written in the User's folders but as far as the parsing is concerned, this will be an efficient tool, I think.

Comment: Guess I can remove the answer if it's not appropriate for the question.

Comment: the problem is it's not really relevant.  Yes it is helpful in parsing the dates, but given the OP has no problem getting the date as a return value, I don't think this is going to solve his issue.

Comment: Edit: elaborated with some sample code where the parser can be run to extract dates from filename

Comment: hmm... curious why this should be downvoted with the full code here?