# VBA - Find date within text containing format 'DDMMYYYY'

Tags: excel, date, replace, find, vba

I've scanned and found many similar answers to my question although none of them are quite ticking the boxes, so I'll explain what I'm after and hopefully it makes sense:

- I have imported data into an excel spreadsheet (working with 2007) from a TXT, which contains various dates (all in the format DDMMYYYY).
- What I'm trying to do is create a sub routine which finds any dates in this format and subsequently decreases the date by 1 year.
- The dates are within a range when the TXT has been imported (in this instance, the first 2 dates appear under range A6) so ideally I would like to specify that range because I don't necessarily want to decrease all dates present in the TXT.

For example, here's the incorrect code which I am sure needs some serious tweaking!

```
    Cells.Replace What:="Dates", Replacement:="Dates-1", LookAt:=xlPart,    _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=DDMMYYYY, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I gather there is some prior definition that needs to be carried out before anything like the above code would work but if there is anyone who can help, I'd appreciate it!

Many thanks,

Robin.

Comment: if you konw how to define your range to decrease one year you can simply use cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 4) & Right(cell.Value, 4) - 1

Comment: Hi Fabrizio, I don't know how but I guess this is something I can expand on. - Thanks for giving the correct path to follow!

Comment: Please select one of these imported dates, switch to the VB Editor, type `? vartype(activecell)` into the Immediate Window and press Enter. If Excel thinks it is a date, it will display 7.  I expect you will get 5 or 8 because I do not believe the imported values are dates; they just look like dates.

Comment: I do not know if you get a message if an answer is amended so this comment is to make sure you know I have added a few more sentences to my answer.  As I say in my previous comment, I believe these dates are really numbers or strings.  The new sentences explain how I would proceed if there are numbers or strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe any tweak will allow your code to achieve the effect you seek.  I cannot give a definitive answer because I do not quite believe your description.  I hope the information below will allow you to investigate your data and develop an appropriate solution.

You are not, as far as I know, using `SearchFormat` correctly.  You need something like this:

```
With Application.FindFormat
  .Font.Bold = True
End With

Set Rng = .Find(. . .  SearchFormat = True  . . .)
```

The VBA Editor’s Help for `Find` states: “***SearchFormat*** Optional **Variant**. The search format.” but gives no example to show what that means.  I cannot find an example of using the find format facility that is not in the above style.  That is: you use `FindFormat` to specify the format(s) of interest and set `SearchFormat` to True to indicate that those formats are to be searched for.

You could try:

```
With Application.FindFormat
  .NumberFormat = "DDMMYYYY"
End With
```

I have not tried this and I cannot find any documentation that explains what format types can be searched for.  If this works, it will almost certainly be faster and easier than anything based on the following information.

For Excel to import a string within a text file as a Date, it must:

- Recognise the string as a date.
- Convert that string to a number.
- Store that number with a number format that indicates it is a date.

Excel stores dates as the number of days since 1/1/1900.  For example, “21 August 2015” will be stored as 42238 with a number format of “dd mmmm yyyy”.  There is nothing about the cell value that says it’s a date.  You can enter the cell value as 42238 and later set the number format to “dd mmm yy” and the value will display as “21 Aug 15”.

Your description implies the dates are held in the text file as eight-digit values which Excel recognises as dates and therefore sets the number format to "DDMMYYYY".  I have never managed to get Excel to recognise eight-digit values as dates.  If you have succeeded, I would like to know how.

My best suggestion is:

```
For Each CellCrnt in RngImport
  If CellCrnt.NumberFormat = "ddmmyyy" Then
    ' Add year to date
  End If
Next
```

**Extension**

If you perform the actions I requested in the comment against your question, we should be able to identify the type of the values you wish to locate and modify.  This extension explains how you might use that information.

In my earlier code I used `RngImport` to represent the Range of the imported data.  One of your remarks makes me wonder: do you know how to initialise that Range?

Do we have to search the entire Range for these “dates”?  That is, are there scattered across the data or are they restricted to a single column?  The final code will be faster if we do not have to examine every cell.

My guess is we will need something like:

```
If IsDate(Mid(CellValue,1,2) & "/" & Mid(CellValue,3,2) & "/" & Mid(CellValue,5,4)) Then
```

to convert “ddmmyyyy” to “dd/mm/yyyy” and then test the new string to be a date.

Comment: No such luck with this one either unless I am using your suggestion incorrectly! :/

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. - I still don't seem to be able to get this to work. - The biggest issue I guess is that the length of each line containing a date in the format DDMMYYYY may alter, so defining this wouldn't neccessarily help. If anyone has any further suggestions, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Hello, I've sort of gained a solution using a bit of both yours and the initial suggestions relating to identifying a range and then using 'MID' to specify how far along. - I can add a year and then replace the whole string with the updated year...This seems to work. My next issue is I'll need to be able to specify exact dates via an input box, then replace but I'll dig into it before asking another question! - Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
Sub OneYearEarlier()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim dt As Date

    For Each c In Selection
        If c.NumberFormatLocal = "TT.MM.JJJJ" Then
            dt = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, c.Value)
            c.Value = dt
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Firstly, I think you have to handle the cell value as a Date data type, not as a string. This will avoid overflow or underflow which might occur if not decreasing by one year but some other time interval, e.g. one month.
Secondly, as mentioned by others you cannot reliably detect that a number is a date in XL. My code uses
- only cells which you have selected beforehand (e.g. one column)
- only cells with a date format

I use `NumberFormatLocal` here so that the format string is identical to the one which you see in the format dialog/"custom format". But this is not really critical here, just a convenience.

I really dislike having to use both the 'internal' format string "yyyy" and the localized format string "JJJJ" but that's the way `DateAdd` wants it.

Comment: Hello, I tried this one but unfortunately it crashed the system! :/ The closest I got was to try producing a msgbox when using an adapted version of the code. - Unfortunately all this proved is that it wasn't picking up the date from the line of text.

Comment: OK, if you select a cell with a date and start the VBA editor (ALT-F11), what does it say the format is (direct window, "? selection.numberformatlocal" ? Tested it here and it worked (German XL 2003)

Comment: I think the confusion is that although the string contains date information, which happens to be represented in the format DDMMYYYY, the string contains various other data; therefore cannot be defined as a date? - I get that if the cell was assigned a 'date' format, it would pick up the numberformat.local, but I'm not in a position to change the format of the entire cell as this may cause issues with the remaining data. - I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Could you edit your original question to show a sample cell, content and format? If there is other text in the cell surrounding the date then you'll have to use string manipulation to get the date value, decrease it and re-build the cell contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own RegEx function to simplify:

```
    Function RegEx(Target As String, RegExpression As String, _
                   Optional ReplaceString As String, Optional xIgnoreCase As Boolean, _
                   Optional xGlobal As Boolean, Optional xMultiLine As Boolean)
    
        Dim regexOne As Objectv
                
        Set regexOne = New RegExp
        regexOne.Pattern = RegExpression
        If xIgnoreCase Then regexOne.IgnoreCase = xIgnoreCase
        If xGlobal Then regexOne.Global = xGlobal
        If xMultiLine Then regexOne.MultiLine = xMultiLine
        
        If regexOne.Test(Target) Then
            If IsMissing(ReplaceString) Then
                RegEx = regexOne.Execute(Target)
            Else
                RegEx = regexOne.Replace(Target, ReplaceString)
            End If
        End If
    End Function
```

You could use this for your problem in this way:

```
Function fDateAdd(SearchTextas Date, DateUnit as String, ModAmount as Interger)
    
    FoundText = RegEx(SearchText, "######")
    Do
        If IsDate(FoundText) And (Mid(FoundText, 5, 2)="19" Or Mid(FoundText, 5, 2)="20") Then
            ReplaceWithText = DateAdd(DateUnit, ModAmount, CDate(FoundText))
            fDateAdd = Replace(SearchText, FoundText, ReplaceWithText)
        End If
        FoundText = RegEx(SearchText, "######")
    Loop While FoundText <> ""
End Function
```

Comment: Please don't add [identical answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67205159/445425) to different questions.  You need to customise the answer to address the question. In this cae, explain how your function can be used to solve the OPs problem